# Why are multiple threads being inefficiently distributed in this example?

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a test why I can run to get about 5 seconds of 100% CPU usage time on one of my cores.

This is the script

```
from threading import Thread
from time import time, sleep

def test0():
    start = time()
    a = 0
    for _ in range(int(1e8)):
        a += 1
    print(time() - start)
```

This is the trace (Ubuntu 20.04 system monitor with 1 second time bins)

[image]

Cool. That makes sense. One of my CPUs is working at 100% for about 5 seconds.

Now what happens if I try to run 4 threads which each do the same thing? With my current knowledge, I would think that they should be time distributed on one core and the whole thing should take about 20 seconds. Here's the script

```
def print_after_work(msg):
    a = 0
    for _ in range(int(1e8)):
        a += 1
    print(msg)
    

def test1():
    threads = []
    for i in range(4):
        threads.append(threading.Thread(target=print_after_work, args=[i+1]))
    start = time()
    for thread in threads:
        thread.start()
        sleep(0.2)
    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()
    print(time() - start)
```

And here's the trace:

[image]

So we have 4 CPUs working at about 25% capacity.

Questions:

1. So Python's `threading` module can move threads to different cores other than the main process?
2. If so, then why only use 25% of each core taking 4x as long to do it?

Comment: Read about python GIL
https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock


https://opensource.com/article/17/4/grok-gil

Comment: In Summary - Python threads do not use multiple cores because All threads share common data internally.

Comment: @AvihayTsayeg makes sense now that the sum across all cores is 100%. But still not sure about the answer to my first question.

Comment: @TonySuffolk66 then why are multiple cores working in my example?

Comment: @AlexanderSoare O/S Timeslicing - the Python process itself is almost certainly getting swapped between Cores at each time slice. There is no guarantee that a process will be pegged to the same core all the time. Your graph isn't showing the granularity of that O/S timeslice. So what you are seeing is a an aggregate over time of the 4 cores.

Comment: Thanks @TonySuffolk got it now. Feel free to drop it as an answer and I'll mark solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python threads do not use multiple cores because All threads share common data internally: [Python GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock).

What you are seeing in your graph is the aggregated effect of OS Timeslicing - the Python process itself is almost certainly getting swapped between Cores at each time slice. There is no guarantee that a process will be pegged to the same core all the time. Your graph though isn't showing the granularity of that O/S timeslice. So what you are seeing is a an aggregate over time of the 4 cores, which means that you are getting 25% of each CPU or the equivalent of 100% of one CPU - as you would expect to see on Python multi-threadings where the threads are all pegged to the same CPU when the process itself is scheduled.